# ASP.NET MVC handles 404 errors differently on local IIS and when deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a controller where an action returns a 404 error on ASP.NET MVC. Working locally, I get the page with 404 error correctly. When I deploy it to azure, instead of the page, I only get a text-only page:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

I've tried all three values on on `customErrors` mode in `web.config` (mode = Off, On, RemoteOnly) and it doesn't seem to change anything at all.

Why is Azure behaving differently on 404 errors and how can I make it behave the same as local IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found out the problem. Apparently, it wasn't even hitting the ASP.NET's custom errors handler, and was being caught at server level.

I've played with `web.config` and added this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
    <remove statusCode="500"/>
</httpErrors>
```

It now passes my error to the ASP.NET's custom error handler correctly.